# Memoization: concatenating params or performing md5 hash?

Tags: php, memoization

I am adding memoization to several functions. These functions take 2-3 string parameters (object names), an optional int parameter (record ID), and a boolean parameter (include deleted records). Each combination of parameters is guaranteed to produce a unique result (thus worth caching).

I am wondering if it would be faster to concatenate the given parameters (`$param1 . $param2 . $param3` etc) and use that as the array key, or to take the same concatenated string and use the md5 hash as the key. The length of the concatenated parameter string is between 20-32 characters in 99% of cases (averaging around 27), whereas an md5 hash is always 32 characters.
***Edit***: an md5 hash is only 16 bytes, not 32. Thanks Mjh.

I am leaning toward the first option, as it:

- saves me the cost of performing the md5 hash
- it will usually save a few bytes of memory (27 average vs 32 hashed) *(Mjh pointed out this is not true: md5 is only 16 bytes)*, and
- since an md5 hash is just another string it will usually be faster to compare the shorter string

The only reason I'm doubting this is that the vast majority of memoization functions seem to use (md5) hashes, so I am wondering if I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** I forgot to mention: I separate the individual parameters with a `#` character, which can never naturally occur in any of the parameters.

**P.P.S.** So far ankhzet's comment seems to be the best solution given my strings are practically unique to begin with: `crc32($paramString)`. Small memory footprint, and a very quick checksum calculation function.

---

#### Testing crc32() performance

Below is a testing script which fills 4 arrays with 1 million `key => value` pairs each. The `values` of all 4 arrays are identical. The `keys` are also identical, except that for the first 2 arrays the concatenated string-keys first have `crc32()` run on them.

```
$test1Array = [];
$start1 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $test1Array[crc32("pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $i . "#" . 1)] = "test " . $i;
}
$end1 = microtime(true);

$test2Array = [];
$start2 = microtime(true);
for ($j = 0; $j < 1000000; $j++)
{
    $test2Array[crc32("pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $i . "#" . 1)] = "test " . $j;
}
$end2 = microtime(true);

$test3Array = [];
$start3 = microtime(true);
for ($x = 0; $x < 1000000; $x++)
{
    $test3Array["pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $i . "#" . 1] = "test " . $x;
}
$end3 = microtime(true);

$test4Array = [];
$start4 = microtime(true);
for ($y = 0; $y < 1000000; $y++)
{
    $test4Array["pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $i . "#" . 1] = "test " . $y;
}
$end4 = microtime(true);
```

Results of 3 test runs:
Test 1: 3.9902291297913
Test 2: 3.6312079429626
Test 3: 0.91605305671692
Test 4: 0.91405177116394

Test 1: 3.9842278957367
Test 2: 3.6172070503235
Test 3: 0.91405200958252
Test 4: 0.918053150177

Test 1: 3.9842278957367
Test 2: 3.6282079219818
Test 3: 0.91205215454102
Test 4: 0.91605186462402

If I take the average of all "Test 2" and "Test 4" values (since "Test 1" seems to have initialisation overhead), I am left with 3.6255409717560 for "Test 2" and 0.9160522619883 for "Test 4". That is a difference of 2.7094887097677, and (2.7094887097677 / 1000000) = 0.0000027094887 or 2.72 microseconds per function call.

Unfortunately I can't easily calculate memory usage at the moment, but storing the 4 byte `crc32()` value is guaranteed to take significantly less memory than the average 27-character length strings. Assuming best-case scenario 1 byte characters, that is a difference of 23 bytes per cached result.

---

For completeness I ran a quick test with `md5()` as well:
Test 1: 4.2855787277221
Test 2: 3.8108838399251
I am actually surprised by how little performance difference there is between `md5()` and `crc32()`. Of course, `crc32()` still has the advantage of using only 4 bytes to `md5()`'s 16.

---

**Conclusion**: since the main overhead of my functions is in the repeated database calls, and since these functions are called on the order of around 50-200 times per request, I personally think the ~135-540 microseconds of added computing time is worth saving the ~1150-4600 bytes of memory.

If anyone disagrees with my tests and/or conclusion, I'd love to know.

Comment: With either approach, are you guaranteed to avoid [collisions](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/)?

Comment: @summea Well, md5 hash collision chance is very low to begin with. With my concatenated parameter string collisions are virtually impossible, since each combination of parameters refers to either a specific object-type in my system, or a specific record of that object-type.

Comment: With the implication being that a collision is practically guaranteed to be the cached result I'm looking for to begin with.

Comment: `md5` takes up 16 bytes, not 32. It takes up 32 when we represent the hash as string, but in its binary format it's less. Using something like `$memoized_index = md5(json_encode(func_get_args()), true);` shouldn't be slow at all, nor memory intensive. That's at least how I would go about it.

Comment: If you concerned about performance, wny not use simple builtin `crc`? It grand faster than md5, with unique and short source strings collisions have quite same chance as md5 (but that can be easily tested), and requires only 32/64 bit integer as a key... Else, I'd also preffer simple concatenation...

Comment: @ankhzet Hmmm, the `crc32()` does seem to be a nice, quick solution, trading in a tiny bit of the speed-gain (by calculating the checksum) for significantly less memory usage (by swapping a 25-30 character string for a 4 byte integer).

Comment: @Mjh Personally I would never use a `json_encode()` here, but manually concatenate my params (my function doesn't work with a variable argument count anyway). `json_encode()` adds too much overhead for my taste (function call stack, returning much more "stringified" data than required).

Comment: Yeah, used in diff calculation algo for big texts (100k+ lines),  couple of years ago on php 5.+, was quite efficient. Just make sure to test for collisions on production scale data.

Comment: @ankhzet I added tests and a conclusion to my original question. Perhaps you find it interesting. EDIT: also, if you add your original suggestion as an answer I will accept it, since it is the solution I will actually use.

Comment: Mmm, tested with php 7 (2x2.3GHz, 1GB free ram), got `1.3896489143372, 1.1757810115814, 0.99707007408142, 0.98535180091858`. Seems like direct hash usage has the same performance, but crc32 calculation is like 2-4 times faster... I'll try also with integer-key arrays in couple of minutes.

Comment: @ankhzet I am using PHP 5.5.8 on my local 4x3.4GHz machine with just under 2GB free ram. I also added a small `md5()` test just now.   **EDIT:** when I change the process priority to "high" I can squeeze ~3-4% extra performance out of it.

Comment: @Bison so if you accept an array as a parameter, how do you concatenate it for memoization purposes?

Comment: @Mjh I would have to think about that. Currently all the functions I'm implementing caching on take some simple string/int/boolean params, retrieve stuff from the database and perform some logic on that. Especially the DB calls are expensive and avoidable. If the function took an array of arguments I'd probably concatenate with a loop (or array walk, whichever you prefer). A multidimensional array would be another story again. Either way, I always test to see if the caching **actually** sped things up. I never just assume it did.

Comment: @Mjh And even then, you'd have to balance processing time vs. memory used. If the data influencing the results of the calls doesn't change often (or if you can invalidate the cache whenever it does), you can shift from per-request caching to session caching, or even to a cross-user shared-cache (think memcache). A cross user cache obviously will only work if a function will return the same results with the same params, even if called by different users/sessions.

Comment: @Mjh I only just realised you are referring to my comment about not using `json_encode()` from earlier. And yes, in that scenario it might be beneficial to use a `json_encode()`, or a `var_export()`, or any other function along those lines.

Comment: You said that db calls are expensive and avoidable. How did you conclude that? That's not true, it's quite the opposite, especially if you serve php via `php-fpm`. Are you sure you won't repeat database's work twice? Databases are extremely efficient with their caches, I've witnessed hundreds of sites where developers tried to be "smart" about performance and they made their sites slower.

Comment: @Mjh The very act of putting together the query, replacing params and querying the database costs time. Sure, databases are very efficient at what they do, but simply the act of interfacing with another system like that is going to be slower than retrieving the desired result straight from (RAM)memory. Obviously, the act of creating the cache costs time, so functions which might be called only a few times with the same params are likely not worth caching. That is the reason it's crucial to **always** test the actual gain/loss of the caching implementation.

Comment: Sadly, I've to be the bad guy here and state again that this isn't true. Using prepared statements sorts out the problem of lexing queries. `php-fpm` keeps database connections open, instead of opening and closing them on each request. There's no handshake involved at all for subsequent requests. What you will achieve is doubling your RAM usage, for questionable performance gain. Pulling a record from the db isn't so slow that you need to memoize and create the whole caching system, which itself incurs overhead that's MUCH greater than database's lexing overhead.

Comment: Also, the database call is usually not the only thing that my function does. In a permission-checking function, for example, it would then compare the fetched results to some other data, to eventually come to a boolean `true`/`false` conclusion. Storing that conclusion allows you to skip the 1-2 database calls, as well as all logic between them and the `return` statement. Adding caching to certain functions made them 20-70x faster (profiled using XDebug).

Comment: In the end, it's your system and your code, I won't attempt to force my opinion on you. I don't know your code, and if you say it increases your performance 70 times then that's great. I made a suggestion how to create a wrapper for memoization (I'd pass object/method with parameters to memoizer which will either pull from cache or execute the given method with params, hence json_encode with func_get_args()).

Comment: Prepared queries only work if you perform the same query many times successively. In my situation, the same function might be called with the same params 50x in a request, but in total 200x times, and in various mixed up orders. Like I mentioned before, I never just "assumed" there was a speed-up. I measured, amongst other things with XDebug, and noticed not only profiled gains, but also actual real-world page load times dropping from 5-7 seconds to 1-1.5 seconds.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that. I like a good discussion where my views are challenged. I'll defend them, and maybe I'll stick to them, or maybe I'll realise I'm wrong. In which case I've learned something, which is always my goal being on Stackoverflow. So, please don't hesitate to call me out on mistakes. :)

Comment: You've got a heavy loading page there, even 1.5 second is a bit much. Have you thought of using background task runners which construct these pages and then simply show the pre-rendered/cached one? If you don't mind me asking, what is it that PHP does that takes so many iterations and resources?

Comment: @Mjh Yes, I agree that it is a heavy load, and should be done much faster. Unfortunately, I'm the sole programmer responsible for creating the CMS this and other websites run in, and I'm given **very** limited time to spend on optimalisation. The page in question is for a real-estate agency and loads in 50 real-estate properties, including an image and many attributes and custom fields from different tables. There is one major optimisation I've already implemented but haven't placed live yet, which is that currently more fields are retrieved than are shown in the list (which I've remedied now)

Comment: @Mjh Also, about the background task runners: unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) I'm only responsible for the backend systems. Another colleague handles the frontend, and my input/advice for that side is largely ignored. So I do the best I can to make my part as good and fast as I can make it. ;)

Comment: Alright, in that case - I wish you the best of luck fighting that beast and I hope this memoization optimization does the trick :) have a nice day!

Comment: @Mjh Thanks, you too. And thanks for the good discussion, I enjoyed it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my naive perfomance test for md5-crc32-sha1-native hashing on AMD 2x2.3 GHz machine with PHP7:

```
function probe($label, $times, $callback) {
    $mem = memory_get_usage();
    $start = microtime(true);
    $array = $callback($times);
    $time = microtime(true) - $start;
    $mem = sprintf('%.3f', (memory_get_usage() - $mem) / 1024 / 1024);
    return "$label:  $time s, $mem MB";
}

$times = 1000000;

$run1 = probe('String key', $times, function ($times) {
    $a = [];
    while ($times-- > 0) {
        $a["pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $times . "#" . 1] = "test " . $times;
    }
    return $a;
});

$run2 = probe('CRC32 key', $times, function ($times) {
    $a = [];
    while ($times-- > 0) {
        $a[crc32("pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $times . "#" . 1)] = "test " . $times;
    }
    return $a;
});

$run3 = probe('MD5 key', $times, function ($times) {
    $a = [];
    while ($times-- > 0) {
        $a[md5("pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $times . "#" . 1)] = "test " . $times;
    }
    return $a;
});

$run4 = probe('SHA1 key', $times, function ($times) {
    $a = [];
    while ($times-- > 0) {
        $a[sha1("pagemanagement" . "#" . "staticblocktype" . "#" . $times . "#" . 1)] = "test " . $times;
    }
    return $a;
});

echo join("<br/>\n", [
    $run1,
    $run2,
    $run3,
    $run4,
    ]);
```

> String key: 1.2421879768372 s, 111.923 MB
>   CRC32 key: 1.3447260856628 s, 58.517 MB
>   MD5 key: 2.1748039722443 s, 111.923 MB
>   SHA1 key: 2.2480459213257 s, 119.552 MB

Looks like MD5 is a little bit slover than crc32, while crc32 obviously has less memory overhead.

[Here](https://3v4l.org/rJhob) you can find same test (but x10 less iterations, as server memory limitations for test process is 64MB) for PHP5.5+-PHP7 & hhvm versions.

---

**Edit**: Added rough memory allocation test (demo link also updated). Looks like `crc32` takes around 1.5-2 times less memory on proposed test set.

**Edit**: Added sha1 test. Looks even slower and havier that md5.

*Note: shuffling tests order changes nothing, so, no warm-up/memory allocation havily influences results.*

Comment: Your last note is interesting. Any ideas why in my tests the first one always took significantly longer than the second one, even though they were identical copy-pastes? (Minus changed array variable name) And the 3rd and 4th, again identical copies, did give almost the exact same result.

Comment: Process initialization and initial heap allocation takes time. In production that will be handled by code prior to in-memory cache fill due to usual code flow, as most of cpu cycles in suggested test is taken by key generation/copying/allocation and array hash tables fill process. With more free process heap that will run quicker.

Answer (score 1):

When you store this in the array:

```
$cache[$paramString] = $value;  // or
$cache[crc32($paramString)] = $value;
```

PHP is going to create a hash from the key which it stores as an unsigned long.  It will also store the actual $paramString along with other data needed.  So, I don't see that you are really gaining anything from doing the crc32() or md5() especially since the $paramString will not normally be that large.

This page has a lot of details:  https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: If you using `crc` integer keys, you can also use sparse array with integer indicies (`SplFixedArray`) as in-memory cache storage, which has less memory footprint/cpu overhead and don't use string-comparing hashes, afaik...

Comment: SplFixedArray is not a sparse array from what I read:  "The main differences between a SplFixedArray and a normal PHP array is that the SplFixedArray is of fixed length"

Comment: Uh, was wrong with `sparse` bit. Stil, `SplFixedArray` _is_ an _integer-key_ hash map and thus is more performant and memory efficient than simple `array()` for the purpose of key-value in-memory storage (cache), when `crc`-ed integer keys used. And _stil_, any approach is under question without performance tests...

Answer (score -1):

Concatenating the values will only work if the toString method for the objects does not hide any features which affect the behaviour of the functions, and the function does not instantiate anything dependant on any hidden features. But since we're talking about object orientation, we can't be sure that the size of the concatenated strings will be predictable.

So for that reason alone you should be using a hash.

You might consider using sha1() which despite being more complex than md5() actually runs a lot faster (at least the last time I checked).

But this smells like premature optimization to me.

Comment: OP meant concatenation of function arguments, not result object parameters... Anyway, if `concatenation of parameters` not enought to 'uniqualy' identify desired function result, then `hash of concatenation of parameters` also wouldn't. And hash of result object has nothing to do with caching, as to compare hashes to extract desired object you'll be forced to get function result object in order to get it's hash, which is contradictoinary to cache usage purpose, no?..

Comment: So it will return the same value / carry out the same action regardless of the actual values passed to it? That's a novel approach to programming.

Comment: "_it will return the same value_" - how, exactly, you got such a conclusion? Function result is production of function params, same params always generate same result, such behaviour can be cached. If same params can produce different results (via non-deterministic inner state of result object, as you implying in yours answer), then caching is impossible, no matter, is key hashed or not.

Comment: @symcbean You misunderstood the use of these functions. One example of a function is to retrieve an `object_id` from the `objects` database table. The function in that case takes the parameters `$moduleName`, `$objectName` and `$enabledObjectsOnly`. By the very architecture of the system the module-object name combination is unique. So **for the same parameters**, the output is always the same. Wikipedia: `A function can only be memoized if it is referentially transparent; that is, only if calling the function has exactly the same effect as replacing that function call with its return value`

Comment: Also, memoization/result caching is **FAR** from a premature optimisation. By applying it to several highly-used functions I managed to get a ~50% page load speed increase. (It is a database driven system, and database calls are relatively expensive.)